# Border to select element in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I would like to add border to select element.

The problem is in firefox (version 29.0.1) that add a background to the arrow, that I don't want and I wish the arrow background stay white.

You can see the code below (the select with the id select 2 is the one with the border):

```
#select2 {border:1px solid #999;}
<select id='select1'>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<select id='select2'>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

There is also fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RmfQ3/)

and an image:
[image]

I want the firefox select element will look like the chrome (gray border on the select and white background on the arrow).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this css and custom image for dropdown:

```
#select2 {
    border:1px solid #999;
    outline : none;
    overflow : hidden;
    text-indent : 0.01px;
    text-overflow :'';
    background : url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/arrow_sans_down-16.png") no-repeat right 2px center;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width:80px;//You can use custom dimension
}
select.#select2 :: -ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/RmfQ3/2/

Comment: You can try this: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/ . But I am not sure it will work the way you want. Also, you can try this plugin for selectbox: http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/